# What are the persistent framework types?

Tags: frameworks, persistent

I wonder what kind of persistent frameworks we use on software. I don't know, maybe my question is wrong. We are using a persistent framework to handle our data layer. We'r using Relational Database. But I don't know which kind of persistent framework we use. In my job interview, I am asked which persistent framework do we use, and I couldn't answer. How many persistent framework exists ? And how can I understand which one is ours.
In our framework, we define our business objects (classes), and database is generated on runtime. (columns and tables) We don't write SQL statements, they are all generated on runtime. 
Tomorrow, I need this answer :) Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is a really confusing question. It sounds like an interviewer expected you to know specifics about their software? Do you have intimate knowledge of their facility before entering the interview?

Have you looked up the term? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_framework

The database is a storage layer, and because you dont write sql statements directly, you are using some kind of framework in the middle to map the classes of your business logic to data that can be stored. Whatever is providing that layer would be the persistence layer. The wiki link names some. If you use python, sqlalchemy or django could be an example as well.

Overall Im not sure why you know part of this companies setup but only part.

Comment: I try to find the logic of our framework. Which theory they used? I need to know that. I am working at this company, but I'm novice on frameworks, therefore I need some information about frameworks to find which theory we use in that framework. I hope I am clear on my purpose.

Comment: No one is going to be able to answer this for you unless you know what piece of software it is. Is it custom? Is it an open source framework with a name?